# Event handling for a button in a Silverlight DataGridColumnHeader

Tags: wpf, silverlight, events, datagrid, styles

I have a Silverlight 5 project with a Styles.xaml and another class where I create a DataGrid at runtime. I want to have buttons in the DataGridColumnHeader to realize some kind of filter function. The style is defined as the following:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridFilterStyle" TargetType="sdk:DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="Auto">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0.2"/>
                        <Button Content="Foo" Margin="5,0" x:Name="filter" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then, I generate a DataGrid at runtime. I do not know the parent page because it's generic:

```vb
dg = New DataGrid
dg.AutoGenerateColumns = False
dg.RowHeight = 28
' Doing some stuff here....
dg.ColumnHeaderStyle = Application.Current.Resources("DataGridFilterStyle")
gd.Children.Add(dg)  ' gd is a Grid as a parent container
```

So, I have my Styles.xaml and a separate class where I do some events. How can I add a click event to the buttons in my DataGridColumnHeader (filter)? Normally, it wouldn't be a problem if the style and the code are in the same file.

Thanks for any help!

Regards

Daniel

Comment: Have you tried using a [command](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-4-How-to-Command-Control.aspx) on the button, instead of a `Click` event handler?

Comment: Ok, working with commands solved my problem!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0.2"/>
        <Button Content="Foo" Margin="5,0" x:Name="filter" Click="filter_Click" /> //xaml
    </StackPanel>

private void filter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //code behind
    {

    }
```

I hope this will help

Comment: Sorry, not really, because the sub is not in the same code as the xaml. The style is defined in Styles.xaml which does not have a code-behind, and the event handler should be defined in another class.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the button control in code behind itself where you are setting the datagrid headerstyle. You need to first remove the TemplateBinding **Height="{TemplateBinding Height}**"

The below is the code to get the button control in code behind.

```
 var style =  Application.Current.Resources["DataGridFilterStyle"] as Style;
        dataGrid1.ColumnHeaderStyle = style;
        style = dataGrid1.ColumnHeaderStyle;
        var setter = style.Setters.FirstOrDefault();
        var k = setter as Setter;
        var val = k.Value as DataTemplate;
        var obj = val.LoadContent() as Grid;
        var button = (obj.Children[0] as StackPanel).Children[1];
```

Hope this could solve your problem.

Cheers!
Vinod

Comment: That's a good example and I can get the button and change its properties. But they will not be taken back into the style. So, if I add the click event, or even change the Content property, I can not see the changes. Maybe, I have to put back the changed button object into the style. But how would I accomplish this?